# Using generic TableQuery type on parent trait

Tags: scala, types, type-mismatch

I am quite new to Scala programming. Besides Scala, I have never learned functional programming. With that said, I am currently trying to figure out a good way to define traits, classes, etc, on a project using slick.

My idea was to have a trait having the methods to be implemented on the child classes, and some would be implemented on the parent class itself. I found a way that works but I have no idea why. Not sure if this problem is related to how Slick or Scala works.

I was using a construction like:

```
trait CompanyDAO extends BaseDao[Company]{
 self: DBProfile  =>
```

But this give the following type mismatch error:

> [error]  found   :
>   slick.lifted.TableQuery[CompanyDAO.this.CompanyTable] [error] 
>   required:
>   slick.lifted.TableQuery[CompanyDAO.this.profile.api.Table[Company]]
>   [error]     (which expands to) 
>   slick.lifted.TableQuery[CompanyDAO.this.profile.Table[Company]]
>   [error] Note: CompanyDAO.this.CompanyTable <:
>   CompanyDAO.this.profile.api.Table[Company], but class TableQuery is
>   invariant in type E. [error] You may wish to define E as +E instead.
>   (SLS 4.5) [error]   override def toTable = TableQuery[CompanyTable]

But, if I use

```
self: DBProfile with BaseDao[Company] =>
```

Then the compilation works (BTW, got the solution from [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44184904/how-to-do-i-pass-tablequery-as-a-generic-and-then-use-it))

So, my questions:

1) Why using self-types toTable assignment works while extending the trait do not? How scala interprets the type of toTable in both scenarios?

2) Is there a way to adapt the "trait CompanyDAO extends BaseDao" to solve the error?

Thank you in advance.

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import slick.basic.DatabaseConfig
import slick.jdbc.JdbcProfile

trait DBConfiguration {
  lazy val config = DatabaseConfig.forConfig[JdbcProfile]("mytrade")
}

trait DBProfile {
  val config: DatabaseConfig[JdbcProfile]
  val db: JdbcProfile#Backend#Database = config.db
  val profile : JdbcProfile = config.profile
}

trait BaseDao[T <: Any] {
  self: DBProfile =>

  import profile.api._
  import slick.lifted.TableQuery

  def toTable():TableQuery[Table[T]]
  def findAll():Future[Seq[T]] = db.run(toTable.result)
}

case class Company(name: String, code: Int)

// If I use the construction like the comment below, it will fail
//trait CompanyDAO extends BaseDao[Company]{
    //self: DBProfile  =>

trait CompanyDAO {
  self: DBProfile with BaseDao[Company] =>
  //import from DBProfile trait
  import profile.api._

  class CompanyTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[Company](tag, "COMPANY") {

    import slick.ast.BaseTypedType
    import slick.jdbc.JdbcType

    def name = column[String]("name")
    def code = column[Int]("code")

    def * = (name, code) <> (Company.tupled, Company.unapply)
  }

  override def toTable = TableQuery[CompanyTable]
}
```

**EDIT: some other things I have been trying**

Extending BaseDao, If I change the declaration of toTable to:

```
def toTable[S <: TableQuery[Table[_]]]():S
```

The type mismatch goes away but I receive now:

> test.scala:27: dead code following this construct [error]   def
>   findAll():Future[Seq[T]] = db.run(toTable.result)

Tried also using self-type and it gave me the same error.

Comment: 1) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224932/difference-between-trait-inheritance-and-self-type-annotation
2) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990948/what-is-the-difference-between-self-types-and-trait-subclasses
3) https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/219038/what-is-the-difference-between-self-types-and-trait-inheritance-in-scala

Answer (score 0):

> If I change the declaration of toTable to:
>
> `def toTable[S <: TableQuery[Table[_]]]():S`
>
> The type mismatch goes away but I receive now:
>
> ```
> test.scala:27: dead code following this construct [error] def findAll():Future[Seq[T]] = db.run(toTable.result)
> ```
>
> Any ideas why is this happening?

I can't reproduce your specific compile error.

But when I change the line

```
def toTable():TableQuery[Table[T]]
```

to

```
def toTable[S <: TableQuery[Table[_]]]():S
```

I have compile error

```
Error:(24, 51) value result is not a member of Nothing
    def findAll():Future[Seq[T]] = db.run(toTable.result)
```

This is because type parameter `S` is inferred to be `Nothing`.

You don't provide implementation for the method `toTable` and `Nothing <: TableQuery[Table[_]]`.

Comment: Thank you for the references, really helpful. Just for reference, I am using Scala 2.12.1 with Slick 3.2.0. What I cannot understand is why toTable(): TableQuery[Table[T]] works with self-types and do not work if I use inheritance. How scala interprets the type of this variable in each case, what is the logic?